# How to record my created instrumental music on FL Studio?

Tags: fl-studio

I am a beginner in FL Studio software, for making an instrumental tune, I created a tune but I am spend lots time to record that tune but failed to save it, can any one help me  ** to record my created instrumental music on FL Studio?**

Comment: You need to tell us more. Provide a list with each step you did. Also post the exact error message if there was one. You can edit your question and add this information.

Comment: Start by reading the manual - https://www.image-line.com/fl-studio-learning/fl-studio-online-manual/

Comment: By any chance, are you using the demo version of FL Studio? I've heard that the demo version is no good at saving your music files.